# Reason for hardness of optimal minimization, and use of iterative optimizers

Tags: geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry

Suppose a set of $n-1$ are given in 2D space, $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1}$, and an additional point $x_n$ is to be assigned a 2D coordinate such that the prescribed Euclidean distances $d_1, d_2, \dots, d_{n-1}$ of this points to points $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1}$ are matched as best as possible in least-squares sense.

In other words, a function to be optimized is: $$f(x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (d_i-\|x_i-x_n\|)^2,$$ is minimized. An approach to achieve the minimimum is to adapt some form of iterative minimizers (at least in the literature I have on disposal). However, an approach to minimize the function is to find its derivative wrt $x_n$, set it to zero,$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}f(x_n)=0,$$ and solve for $x_n$. Why is such approach not applicable here? Is is due to hardness of finding a derivative (or impossibility to find one), or due to computational effort?

Comment: How are $d_i$ defined exactly, or are they just constants?

Comment: @HaukeStrasdat Values of $d_i$ are arbitrary positive constants, not necessarilly equal.

Comment: In the general case, there will usually be many *local* minimas. If you simply start at some point and "follow" the gradiant, chances are high that you will end at some local minimum, not the global one.

Comment: Hm, the first thing which comes to my mind is that $g_i(x_n) :=  (d_i-||x_i-x_n||)^2$ does not approximate zero at the minimum $(x_n,f(x_n))$ since $d_i$ are arbitrary. So it is strictly speaking not a least-squares problem and thus the Gauss-Newton method is no applicable, AFAIK. Did you try another iterative method such as gradient descent or the Newton method?

Comment: @HaukeStrasdat Well, the point is that iterative methods such as gradient descent is often used. But, why can't one just set the derivative of $f(x_n)$ wrt $x_n$ to zero, and solve for $x_n$?

Comment: A good way to see that the residuals $g_i\top g_i$ have to be small (at least around the minimum), is to derive Gauss-Newton from the more general Newton method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm#Derivation_from_Newton.27s_method

In the Newton method the Hessian of f is:  $H_f = J_g^\top J_g  + H_g \cdot g$ (with $H_g$ being the second derivative of $g$). In the Gauss-Newton method (=least-squares), the Hessian is approximated as $H_f = J_g^\top J_g$ which is only valid if $g :=  (g_1,...,g_{n-1})$ is small. I don't know whether this is true in your case...

Comment: Notr that the derivative is undefined at $x_n = x_i$. So these are critical points and candidates for minimums.

Comment: @user506901: I was implicitly assuming you are using Gauss-Newton, but maybe it is not the case. Could you write down how your linear system looks like?

Comment: @hardmath So, the argument is that the derivative cannot be found, and therefore one has to adopt, eg, gradient descend?

Answer (score 0):

Let's write the parameters $y = (u,v)$ and the function to be minimized as:

$$f(y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (d_i-\|x_i-y\|)^2 $$

Since $f(y)$ tends to $+\infty$ uniformly as $y$ recedes from the origin, this continuous function does attain a global minimum, and the general theory tells the minimum is attained at a critical point (since no boundary is involved), i.e. at a point [where either the first partial derivatives are all zero or some are undefined](http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Critical_point_for_a_function_of_multiple_variables).

This problem is nonetheless much harder than a linear least squares fitting problem because the latter ordinarily has a unique critical point where partials vanish which can be determined by solving a linear system.

There are multiple critical points of the "undefined derivative" kind, as pointed out in the comments.  These at least are known a priori as $y = x_i$, since elsewhere the first partial derivatives $\partial f/\partial u, \partial f/\partial v$ are defined and bounded.

Further consider finding critical points where first partials vanish simultaneously using this formula:

$$ \partial f/\partial u = 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (\|x_i-y\| - d_i)  \frac{(u - x_i^{(1)})}{\|x_i - y \|} $$

and the corresponding expression for $\partial f/\partial v$.  Since $u,v$ appear in the denominator via $y$ and and inside a radical courtesy of the norm of $x_i - y$, a pair of such simultaneous equations (setting the first partials to zero) will be quite nonlinear.